# gravity form preview of image upload

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have made a contact form using "Gravity Form", in which I used image uploader. Now I want to display preview of image to user which is uploading. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: I know its an old thread, but if some one is still looking for an option to preview or edit gravityforms uploaded images, gravity more have introduced a simple addon for that
https://gravitymore.com/addons/gravity-forms-smart-uploads/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, Late Answer

```
<script>

jQuery('#imgview').hide();  

function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        jQuery('#imgview').show();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery('#imgview>img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

// your File input id "#input_1_2"

jQuery(document).on("change","#input_1_2", function(){
    readURL(this);
});
</script>
```

html block

```
<div id="imgview"><img src=""></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! It inspired us to cover this in a bit more depth here: https://gravitywiz.com/add-image-previews-to-gravity-forms-file-upload-fields/