# GravityForm preview thumbnails for the multifile upload field

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to display the preview thumbnail of the multifile upload field. I had followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730931/gravity-form-preview-thumbnails-for-multi-file-upload-field/) but I found that {fileName} had some random string. It’s between {input id} and {file.target_name}.

Ex: `4a017277_input_5_zfKuGrwCd91CyiHy_o_1esroacel59uais19ev1dqa405q.png`.

What is {zfKuGrwCd91CyiHy}?

tmp image's name

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a solution for this. It's not a beautiful way but it worked like a champ.
The random string above was rendered by a function random_str(). My solution is to remove or customizing the function.
File located at path: ../wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/includes/upload.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PQg3.png)